# How can i change activity using login (username and password) ,button ?

Tags: android, android-activity

I created a log in page ( using 2 EditText and one button ) in android and save some local defined username and password .

During execution when user enters the correct data then it changes its activity to next interface where i can keep items on listmenu .

Please help .

Comment: Without using SQL 
using only local variables.

Comment: Your Question is not Clear ,, what exactly you want to do after enters the correct data ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understood from your question is that you want to switch activities.

To change the current activity and start another one you need an `Intent`, that's called once you click on the submit `button`.

First, you need to set your button `OnClick` attribute to `submit` for exemple,

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="submit"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Then add a `submit` method to your log `activity`:

```
public void submit(View view)
{  
//here you put a condition to check if your login and password are correct
//You can for exemple compare them with values that you have in an sqlite database
if(myLogin.equals("correctLogin") && myPassword.equals("correctPassword"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(yourLogActivity.this, yourListMenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: do not use == for strings use the java methods for example .matches() or .contains()

Answer (score 1):

use a class like

```
public class myDataStore{

public static String uid;
public static String pwd; 
}
```

and other option is using Application Class of Android. Your question is not clear,
What exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
  String userName = "Coolman"
  String password = "IamTheKing"


  public void attemptLogin(View view)
{  

// Get the text from the editText that the user put in
 String enteredUserName = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.userNameText)).getText().toString();
 String enteredPassword = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText)).getText().toString();

// This will check to see if their login info matches
if(userName.matches(enteredUserName) && password.matches(enteredPassword))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourListMenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
       // and do what ever else you want to do here
    }

}
```

Set your onclick to attemptLogin, and do not use == to check if a string matches use the method .matches().  Hope this helps!

Comment: Make sure you accept an answer to earn rep at and to show other users what worked for you